# Calculate sales metrics (like past 6 months, past 3 months, sale one year ago etc.) on transaction data in BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, case, query-optimization

I have to create a view in BigQuery with some details of product sales. The measurements to be included in the view are explained below. These measurements have to be calculated **for each product for every day that product is sold**. **A product is identified by unique combination of 5 -6 attributes (in our demo, code1 and code2 columns)**. The date represents the transaction dates.

- **sales_today** -> the sum of sales for each product (combination of code1 and code2) per day.
- **TotSales_previous_3_months** -> the sum of sales for each product in the previous 3 months(without including any sales from current month). for e.g., if we are calculating TotSales_previous_3_months for a product sale on 5th March 2022, we have to sum up the sales of that product from 1st December 2021 to 28th February 2022.
- **TotSales_previous_6_months** -> the sum of sales for each product in the previous 6 months(without including any sales from current month). Follow the same logic as for TotSales_previous_3_months.
- **sale_one_month_ago** -> The sum of sales of the product on this day exactly one month ago. For e.g., if we are calculating sale_one_month_ago for a product sale on 5th March 2022, it would be the sum of sales of that product on 5th February 2022.
- **sale_one_year_ago** -> The sum of sales of the product on this day exactly one month ago. For e.g., if we are calculating sale_one_month_ago for a product sale on 5th March 2022, it would be the sum of sales of that product on 5th March 2021.
- **Unique_count_flag** -> flag = 1 if the number of sales of the product on a day = 1. If the number of sales of the product is more than 1 on a day, flag = 0.

I have created this table (test_sales) with some demo data for understanding.

| code1 | code2 | date | gen | sales |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 2021-02-04 | jerez | 7 |
| 1 | A | 2021-02-04 | abc | 5 |
| 1 | A | 2022-02-04 | wres | 10 |
| 1 | A | 2022-03-04 | tomz | 10 |
| 1 | A | 2022-03-05 | everyz | 10 |
| 1 | A | 2022-05-01 | ben10 | 30 |
| 1 | A | 2022-06-01 | xyx | 10 |
| 1 | A | 2022-06-01 | xya | 5 |
| 2 | A | 2022-05-10 | iqoom | 20 |
| 3 | C | 2022-01-10 | imola | 60 |
| 3 | C | 2022-04-01 | nurburgring | 50 |
| 3 | C | 2022-06-01 | jerez | 30 |

The result set after calculations should be like -

| code1 | code2 | date | gen | sales | sales_today | TotSales_previous_3_months | TotSales_previous_6_months | sale_one_month_ago | sale_one_year_ago | Unique_count_flag |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 2021-02-04 | jerez | 7 | 12 | 0 | 0 | 0 |  | 0 |
| 1 | A | 2021-02-04 | abc | 5 | 12 | 0 | 0 | 0 |  | 0 |
| 1 | A | 2022-02-04 | wres | 10 | 10 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 12 | 1 |
| 1 | A | 2022-03-04 | tomz | 10 | 10 | 10 | 10 | 10 |  | 1 |
| 1 | A | 2022-03-05 | everyz | 10 | 10 | 10 | 10 | 0 |  | 1 |
| 1 | A | 2022-05-01 | ben10 | 30 | 30 | 30 | 30 | 0 |  | 1 |
| 1 | A | 2022-06-01 | xyx | 10 | 15 | 50 | 60 | 30 |  | 0 |
| 1 | A | 2022-06-01 | xya | 5 | 15 | 50 | 60 | 30 |  | 0 |
| 2 | A | 2022-05-10 | iqoom | 20 | 20 | 0 | 0 | 0 |  | 1 |
| 3 | C | 2022-01-10 | imola | 60 | 60 | 0 | 0 | 0 |  | 1 |
| 3 | C | 2022-04-01 | nurburgring | 50 | 50 | 60 | 60 | 0 |  | 1 |
| 3 | C | 2022-06-01 | jerez | 30 | 30 | 50 | 110 | 0 |  | 1 |

***I was able to create the below code to achieve result, but the problem is that this code works fine for small datasets but here I am dealing with around 60 GB of data(~50 columns and ~80 million rows). If I adapt the code given below for the original sales data(which itself is a combination of few tables after joining them) it just long runs. Is there an alternative or efficient way to achieve the results?***

```
with temp as
 (SELECT
  code1,code2,date,gen,sales,
  COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY code1, code2, date) AS cnt,
  SUM(sales) OVER(PARTITION BY code1, code2,date) AS sales_today,
  array_agg(struct(sales as sales,date as date)) over(partition by code1,code2 order by date) as past_records
FROM
  `test_sales`
)

select * except(past_records,cnt), 
  (select ifnull(sum(x.sales),0)
      from unnest(temp.past_records) as x
      where x.date between (date_trunc(temp.date,MONTH) - INTERVAL 3 MONTH) and (date_trunc(temp.date, MONTH) - interval 1 day)) as TotSales_previous_3_months,
  (select ifnull(sum(x.sales),0)
      from unnest(temp.past_records) as x
      where x.date between (date_trunc(temp.date,MONTH) - INTERVAL 6 MONTH) and (date_trunc(temp.date, MONTH) - interval 1 day)) as TotSales_previous_6_months,
  (select ifnull(sum(x.sales),0)
      from unnest(temp.past_records) as x
      where x.date = temp.date - INTERVAL 1 MONTH) as sale_one_month_ago,
  (select ifnull(sum(x.sales),0)
      from unnest(temp.past_records) as x
      where x.date = temp.date - INTERVAL 1 YEAR) as sale_one_year_ago,
  if(cnt = 1,1,0) as Unique_count_flag

from temp
```

Modified Code inspired from Mikhail's approach:-

```
select *, 
  -- extract(year from date) * 12 + extract(month from date) as months,
  -- UNIX_DATE(date) AS days,
  sum(sales) over(product_date) as sales_today, 
  sum(sales) over(product     range between 3  preceding and  1 preceding) as TotSales_previous_3_months,
  sum(sales) over(product     range between 6  preceding and  1 preceding) as TotSales_previous_6_months,
  case when extract(day from date) = 31 and extract(month from date) in (3,12,10,7,5)
        then sum(sales) over(product_by_unix_date range between 31 preceding and 31 preceding)
      when extract(day from date) = 30 and extract(month from date) = 3
        then sum(sales) over(product_by_unix_date range between 30 preceding and 30 preceding)
      when extract(day from date) = 29 and extract(month from date) = 3
        then sum(sales) over(product_by_unix_date range between 29 preceding and 29 preceding)
      else 
        sum(sales) over(product_day range between 1  preceding and  1 preceding)
      end as sale_one_month_ago,

  case when extract(day from date) = 29 and extract(month from date) = 2
        then sum(sales) over(product_by_unix_date range between 366 preceding and 366 preceding) 
      else 
        sum(sales) over(product_day range between 12  preceding and  12 preceding)
      end as sale_one_year_ago

from `river-blade-343102.test.test_sales`

window 
  product as (partition by code1, code2 order by extract(year from date) * 12 + extract(month from date)),
  product_date as (partition by code1, code2, date ),
  product_day as (partition by code1, code2, extract(day from date) order by extract(year from date) * 12 + extract(month from date)),
  product_by_unix_date  as (partition by code1,code2 order by UNIX_DATE(date))
```

Answer (score 2):

Consider below version of your query - it still not the perfect  - but at least it is easier to handle/read and maintain

```
select *, 
  sum(sales) over(product_date) as sales_today,
  sum(sales) over(product     range between 3  preceding and  1 preceding) as TotSales_previous_3_months,
  sum(sales) over(product     range between 6  preceding and  1 preceding) as TotSales_previous_6_months,  
  sum(sales) over(product_day range between 1  preceding and  1 preceding) as sale_one_month_ago,
  sum(sales) over(product_day range between 12 preceding and 12 preceding) as sale_one_year_ago,
from test_sales
window 
  product as (partition by code1, code2 order by extract(year from date) * 12 + extract(month from date)),
  product_date as (partition by code1, code2, date),
  product_day as (partition by code1, code2, extract(day from date) order by extract(year from date) * 12 + extract(month from date))
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

> Is there an alternative or efficient way to achieve the results?
> So, definitely above is an alternative way with its own pros and cons
> Whether it is more efficient - I do think so, but not 100% sure to be honest - it depends on your data - you need to test it against your data and see ...

Comment: Hi Mikhail, I used your approach and it considerably reduced the processing time. Thank you for pointing us in the right direction. The only thing I added was to use case statements to calculate the sale_one_month_ago and sale_one_year_ago, because as per our requirements, we want to handle certain special cases where the days part in the date wont be equal one month ago and one year ago. For e.g, one month ago December 31st will be November 30th, one year ago "2020-02-29" will be "2019-02-28"   etc... I have added the modified code in the question , please take a look. Open to suggestions.

Comment: I will look into this later in a day and get back to you :o)